# How to repoen a closed STDERR in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, io

I encounter a problem where STDERR is been closed by somebody, perhaps by the OS. Then the Ruby application throws errors on every STDERR#write. I have to restart the application to make it reopen.

Is there a way to reopen STDERR within the code? Or I have to use some outside monitor tool to restart the application? Also, what's the possible reasons that STDERR got closed?

The [original issue is here](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache/issues/116).

Comment: The post by Alan Davies might help:  http://www.justskins.com/forums/closing-stderr-105096.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The original issue tells us nothing useful, nor does your question's text. I seriously doubt Rails is closing STDERR, or the OS, as either would trigger a huge storm of problems and complaints. That reduces the problem to something you added to your application or that you wrote. Search the support of any gems or plugins you added looking for similar issues, and carefully review your code. We can't help you without specific code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: It's easy to temporarily redirect any stream, however the onus is upon the developer to restore those immediately after the need for redirection passes. Closing STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR is done when writing code for pipes/sub-profs and daemons but for standard apps we don't do that. It's possible to reopen a closed stream but that is not something you should have to do ever.  Instead look for why it's closing in the first place.

Comment: Patch the stderr object on start up so that any call to close raises. You'll find your offending code real quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch the `$stderr` object so any calls to `$stderr.close` (or equivalent) will raise an error. The code that is closing your `$stderr` will be evident in the resulting stack trace, which will provide insight into your problem.

```
$stderr.instance_exec do
  def close(*)
    raise 'THE GUILTY PAY THE PRICE'
  end
end
```